# Strpos in php not working

Tags: php, text, strpos

I am doing text analysis. I have a table having positive words.The records are being fetched one by one and imploded in an array through mysqli_fetch_array.

```
    while(($rowx = mysqli_fetch_array($resultx,MYSQLI_NUM)))
    {

     $wordx = implode("", $rowx);

        if(strpos($text, $wordx) !== FALSE) 

        {

            $count1 = substr_count($text, $wordx);
            $pos_prob += .2 * $count1;
            echo "pos prob is".$pos_prob;
        }
    }
```

But strpos is not able to match the string that is being fetched from the table.i.e. if text is "It's an excellent book" the if condition is never true. Even though the word excellent is present in the table. And if I hard code the value $wordx as

```
    $wordx='excellent';
```

Only then it works. Does anyone has any idea why this is happening? :( Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: P.S This issue of strpos is different from other cases so please be considerate.

Comment: what if you implode with a space instead of an empty string ? implode(" ", $rowx)

Comment: Where does `$word1` come from? Your code has `$text` and `$wordx`

Comment: jiboulex:  that's not the issue. I've printed the array. The words are being imploded correctly.

Comment: It is likely that your input in `strpos()` is not correct. have you tried: `echo "strpos($text, $wordx)";` to see what the input is?

Comment: Mark Baker: That is $wordx.

Comment: @ KIKO Software : My input is correct. I have checked. That is why when I hard code $wordx, it works.

Comment: Few example outputs:strpos(Its an excellent book, excellent)
strpos(Its an excellent book, excellently)
strpos(Its an excellent book, excels)

Comment: What does your SQL and table structure look like?

Comment: Id and name are the two columns, And I am using query 'SELECT name FROM positive ORDER BY name'

Comment: Okay, then you don't need the implode line.  Just `$wordx = $rowx[0]`, yes?

Comment: It gives the same result as implode.

Comment: Perhaps you have an encoding issue.  Try `mb_strpos()`.

Comment: I've tried. Not working :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the need to implode each row.  My assumption is that each row has one word.

Simple strpos text matching example:

```
<?php

$words = array(
    'big',
    'fat',
    'mamma'
    );

$text = 'One day fat foo walked to the bar';

$matches = array();
foreach($words as $word) {
    if(strpos($text, $word) !== false)
        $matches[] = $word; 
}


var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'fat' (length=3)
```

Note that this would also match word parts and be case sensitive, so not ideal. For example: 'fat' is contained in the words: 'father', 'infatuated' and 'marrowfat'.

Comment: As I am using mysqli_fetch_array, that is why I have to use implode function.

Comment: Can you not reference each row's word something like: `$row['word']` ?  You may be gluing multiple field values together.  But perhaps that's the intention.  What does your SQL and each row look like?

Comment: The output is like this: strpos(Its an excellent book, excellently)

Comment: That is not what I asked.  You need to 'stem' the word 'excellently' in your example above if you want to match 'excellent'.  Search for 'word stemming'.

Comment: Fine. But don't you think for this output ->  "strpos(Its an excellent book, excellent) " it should return false in the if condition.

Comment: I expect `strpos('Its an excellent book', 'excellent')` to return an integer, not false.

Comment: strpos returns false if the string is not found. Check this: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strpos.asp

Comment: Thanks, but  I'm perfectly aware of that.

Comment: Only in this case it should return an integer. But it's not returning anything....